# Security Issue in TexLive: Someone changing the checksums?

Tags: texlive, installing, security

Is someone tampering the checksum files of the TexLive installation on CTAN? Or is it just a server or download issue? If I download the checksum files repeatedly at the same time but using different IP addresses (or at different times of the day), the checksums and/or their signature files are different. The actual installation file seems to remains the same.

Can you confirm this issue, too? If yes, where can I report this issue? And what could be the reason for this issue?

**Details:**
On the [CTAN page of TexLive](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet), download the checksums (and signatures) of the installation files from 2023-09-18. Do it also using VPN or TOR. Depending through which IP address you downloaded it (or at what time of day), you might notice that the checksum files contain different hash codes or that the signature files are different (which results in the signature being invalid for some of the checksum files.

**For example:** I just downloaded `install-tl.zip.sha512` and its signature `install-tl.zip.sha512.asc` three times using Firefox: normally, using VPN, and using the TOR browser. Only in the second case everything was OK. In the other two cases, the checksum file was wrong or the signature was wrong.

First case (downloaded without VPN):
The signature is invalid (but identical to the second case) and `install-tl.zip.sha512` has the following (wrong) content:

```
c2bb496141db1ba17166e34a5f1c64b90ee69919dcf0212967926a358d390ec35359c9ae1d8d774ffeb16db7d455aaaf0b5872bdf5a7fe87a1c17304eb0dfb35  install-tl.zip
```

Second Case (downloaded with VPN):
The signature is correct and `install-tl.zip.sha512` has the following (correct) content:

```
1cbd4eb3a912198334510ee1ef7b6f8b3c4a6af4016eb4ed79755eac4374478d87a96998865f8a2ac008e3376812c0f5f4a7440aa46256d0081121299ebcf20b  install-tl.zip
```

Third Case (downloaded via TOR):
The signature is invalid (is different to the first&second case), however, the content of `install-tl.zip.sha512` is correct:

```
1cbd4eb3a912198334510ee1ef7b6f8b3c4a6af4016eb4ed79755eac4374478d87a96998865f8a2ac008e3376812c0f5f4a7440aa46256d0081121299ebcf20b  install-tl.zip
```

Each time, I also downloaded the actual package `install-tl.zip` and it was identical over all the three cases (its checksum was always as in case 2&3). I did the test several times, and sometimes also in the first case everything was OK.

**Further thoughts:** In my opinion, the download was rather not just corrupt given that the checksum file has been modified very precisely: the part corresponding to the hash code is completely different while the white space afterwards with the part corresponding to the file name remains exactly the same.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Were all the downloads from the same mirror?  Some files xan be out of synch if a mirror happens to be performing an update at the time you've visiting it.  I don't think that all mirrors update on the same schedule.

Comment: Welcome! I would *guess* this is a server/download issue, if only because I can't see why anybody would tamper in this way. If the installation files differed, I could see the point, but why change only the checksum or signature files? (Of course, human motivations are nothing if not multiple and various ....)

Comment: Which ctan mirror did you use? some mirrors update much more frequently than others

Comment: Thank you! I just made another test and got an invalid signature. Here are the mirror details:
`install-tl.zip.sha512` was downloaded from [gwdg.de](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/), and
`install-tl.zip.sha512.asc` from [rrze.uni-erlangen.de](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/).

Comment: The modification dates differ on the servers: 20-Sep-2023 23:46 for the case of [gwdg.de](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/) and 2023-09-21 01:46 for the case of  [rrze.uni-erlangen.de](https://ftp.rrze.uni-erlangen.de/ctan/systems/texlive/tlnet/).

Comment: I just tried both mirrors again and now they give the same files, hence, the signatures are now valid. However, the modifications dates on the server are still the same as before.
I tried also two other servers: [koddos](https://mirror.koddos.net/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet/) (Modification: 2023-09-20 01:46) and [utwente.nl](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/) (Modification: 2023-09-21 01:46). Hence, they differ by one day.

Comment: When downloading the checksum from one of the two mirrors, and the signature from the other one, I got an invalid signature error. 
The reason seems to be that on both mirrors the versions were different: when I downloaded the checksum, signature and zip from the same mirror, then the files were consistent to each other (and the signature valid).

Comment: Thus, the problem seems to be as follows: when I download the checksum and the signature (and the zip), it can happen that they will come all from different mirrors and, hence, be of different versions, which would lead to the inconsistencies I noticed.

Comment: What I still do not understand is why suddenly the versions on gwdg.de and rrze.uni-erlangen.de were the same although the modification date on the server was still shown to be as before when the versions were different. Maybe the modification date is updated a little bit later, or it is some caching issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short:**
The signature file did not match the checksum file as the two files were downloaded from two different servers where the file versions were different.

**Explanation:**
When you download from [CTAN](https://ctan.org/), you actually download from an automatically chosen mirror. Consequently, when you download multiple files, it can happen that each file comes from another mirror.

Since the mirrors are updated at different times, it can happen that the mirrors host different versions of the files.

In my case, when I downloaded the checksum and its supposed-to-be signature, the two files came from two different mirrors where one mirror had an older variant of the files. Thus, the signature was actually a signature for a different version of the checksum file and did not match the checksum file I had downloaded.

**To bypass the issue**, just make sure to download all the files from the same mirror. On the CTAN page, you can [choose a mirror manually](https://ctan.org/mirrors).